# I can't decode a JSON file in Swift, even so I could read it into a Data object

Tags: json, swift

I'm quite new in Swift. I created a simple terminal app inside Xcode to learn about decoding JSON files. Even so I was able to read the file into a Data object, I couldn't decode it for my struct:

Here is my struct:

```
struct Person: Codable
{
    var name: String
    var surname: String
}
```

Here is my simple JSON file:

```
[
    {
        "name": "Abc", 
        "surname": "Def"
    }
]
```

And here is my Swift code to decode the JSON file:

```
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/abcd/Documents/test.json")

if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
{
    print(data) // prints size (in bytes) the data correctly 

    if let person = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Person.self, from: data)
    {
        print(person) // did not printed
    }
}
```

Comment: Your json is an array for some reason. Either remove the surrounding brackets, [], from the file or change the decoding to `[Person].self`. And don't use `try?` when decoding, specially not when you are learning about decoding in swift. Surround your decoding with a proper do/catch and print the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON contains an array. Accordindly, you should use one in your code as well:

```
if let persons = try? JSONDecoder().decode([Person].self, from: data)
    ...
```